# Expression.Call missing overload

Tags: c#, overloading, expression-trees

It's purely an academic question. I noticed that `Expression.Call` in .NET 4.5 offers [many overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call(v=vs.110).aspx) but none of them allows to pass an instance, a `MethodInfo` and **one** single argument. The overload with `params Expression[]` or with `IEnumerable<Expression>` has to be used in that case.

Meanwhile, there is an overload to call *static* methods which takes one argument.

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0)
```

Was the missing version overlooked or is there some obscure reason for it not to be there?

Answer (score 2):

Having taken at the look of [class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/MethodCallExpression.cs#244f8273348d3211#references), it seems extremly fishy in my opinion. All the calls have been optimized pretty hard, except the `Expression.Call(instance, methhodInfo, expression)` which resolves to the overload with `params Expression[]` as you said, which makes no sense - why is that not being optimized, or why are there bunch of `InstanceCallExpression2/3/4/5` classes in the first place?

However, there's a good reason why the static overload exists. That static overload is being shared by Visual basic(as indicated in your link), and VisualBasic doesn't support `params[]` directly, don't get me wrong, you could still access the function without `Expression.Call(methodInfo, Expression f1)`, but in an awkward way:

`Expression.Call(methodInfo, new[]{yourFirstArgExpr});`

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec.aspx), VB.NET does support calling `params` methods just like C# does.

Comment: @svick; good observation. Are the two language-compatible between each other?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't design C#, so I can't say for sure. But I suspect it's because such an overload would be ambiguous with respect to the existing `Call(Expression, MethodInfo, params Expression[])` overload.

That is, the compiler has definite overload resolution rules for this, but it could still be considered confusing to the end-user.